# after adding unique_together constraint, existing data conflicts

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-migrations

I have a model:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    shop = models.ForeignKey('shop.Shop', models.CASCADE, 'products')
```

And there is existing data. Now I want that one shop cannot include products whose names are the same using unique_together:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    shop = models.ForeignKey('shop.Shop', models.CASCADE, 'products')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['name', 'shop']
```

That is ideal for new database, but for exist database exist duplicate names are problem.

How to ignore or except exist data?
How can I apply unique_together to incoming products?

Comment: You can add pseudo unique togetger constraint by overwriting model save method and check in it if there is object with such name and shop. If yes, raise Exception. Better way would be to change names of products if they are not unique together with shop and run migration to add such constraints

Answer (score 0):

I see two different approaches here:

1. Clean data and then make the migration with the `unique_together` constraint
2. Keep current data and add a validation before saving new Product instances

From your description, I understand that you are in favour of the second approach. This a sample code that you can use for this purpose:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Product(BaseModel):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if Product.objects.filter(name=self.name, shop=self.shop).exists():
            raise ValidationError('A product with this name already exists in this shop')
        super().clean()
```

Here the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) with more details about how to override the `clean()` method in a model class.

If you are interested in implementing the first approach instead, I suggest to clean your data using a custom migration just before the `unique_together` introduction or perform a manual check on the DB if you need the verify the duplicates one by one.